# Remote debug node.js from WebStorm: Remote debugging session already active

Tags: node.js, debugging, webstorm

When I remote debug my app in WebStorm, it connects only the first time.  If I stop the remote debugging session in WebStorm and start again, it won't connect to the node server.  I then tried using telnet to connect to the debug port 5858 and found the following:

```
~$ telnet localhost 5858
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Remote debugging session already active
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

It looks like the first remote debugging session was not terminated.  Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: looks like a bug, please vote for [this ticket](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-9090)